# i can't add this object into Firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a feature where the user makes a request to become a vip.So I made a button where i capture firestore dat and insert it into real time data base.For this example i tried to insert just the object "Demandes" with 2 strings "hello",the problem here is the object is not showing up in realtime data base.
Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

```
package com.example.sanad;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;


public class ProfilFragment extends Fragment  {
    View view;
    private TextView logout;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;
    String UID,name,phone;
    Button insert;
    FirebaseDatabase demande;
    DatabaseReference refdemande;
    Context context;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profil, container, false);
        context = container.getContext();

        logout = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.logout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mAuth.signOut();

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class));
            }

        });



        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        UID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("Users").document(UID);

        documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if(document.exists()){
                        name = document.getData().get("nomComplet").toString();
                        // address = document.getData().get("adresse").toString();
                        phone = document.getData().get("numéro").toString();

                        //Toast.makeText(context, name+" "+phone+" "+address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) { }});

         demande = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
         refdemande= demande.getReference("Demandes");

         insert = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.membre);
         insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 demander();
             }
         });



        return view;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
      private void demander(){

        String nom = "hello";
        String num = "hello";

        Demandes Demandes = new Demandes(nom,num);
          refdemande.push().setValue(Demandes);
          Toast.makeText(context, "Demande ajouté" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
}
```

```
package com.example.sanad;

public class Demandes {
    String nom;
    String num;

    public  Demandes(String nom , String num){
        this.nom = nom;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public String getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check if task is not successfull exception

Comment: If your database was created in a non-default region (so outside of the US), you may have to specify it in the code like `demande = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database URL here");`.

Comment: Have you tried to log the error message in onFailure? Have you also tried Frank van Puffelen's suggestion? Does it work?

Comment: Thank you Frank so much ,i needed to add the link of the DataBase.